# How do you make arrows?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I get the materials to make them like other games, but i can't seem to be able to make them.  Is there a quest that has to be done before you can make arrows.

Comment: Be careful not to shoot yourself in the knee.

Comment: fyi there's an arrowsmith mod for skyrim that allows you to craft arrows

Comment: Easiest way by far (if you have the Dragonborn DLC) is to buy them from the smith in Ravenrock. He ALWAYS has around 15-20.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot craft arrows, however...

You *can* farm them, either from some Imperials practicing archery in Solitude, or from Thieves Guild member Cynric Endell doing the same in the Ragged Flagon.

**With Dawnguard DLC**

Now with Dawnguard DLC you can actualy craft arrow from a forge with blacksmith skills. Most of the time you'll need

```
1x Firewood
1x Material (Iron, Dragonbone, Ebony, etc)
```

Example for a Daedric arrow you'll need

```
1x Firewoord
1x Ebony Ingot
1x Daedric Heart
```

So it's now possible to craft arrows if you have the right DLC installed.

Comment: farming is the best way, reverse pickpocket a daedric arrow onto each thieves guild member, steal their other arrows, and gather up whatever they shoot.  You can easily collect 100 daedric arrows in a few minutes in the thieves guild area.

Comment: Wow, @yx, that's brilliant.

Comment: I can confirm @yx's trick works equally well with the Imperial guards in Solitude working on their archery skills...

Comment: I wasn't able to do so in the latest version. Dunno if it's a fixed bug or me doing it wrong, but i stayed behind 30 mins letting them take turns, giving them 1 of my precious 4 arrows and they never shot any deadric arrows back...

Answer (score 9):

No, Bethesda has decided not to do so although there is a crafting file for it in the game. Maybe they'll patch it later?

But for the moment no, just scour the world shops and buy the arrows at the stores.

Comment: i was doing that but no one has daedric arrows

Comment: @doger Daedric arrows are exceptionally rare. Your best bet is the Fletcher in Solitude and finding them as drops.

Comment: I find that the more your level grows, the higher the drops are. I'm level 36 now and i find much more glass in shops and in drops than before. So my guess is that deadric arrows will start dropping eventually around level 45 and become much frequent around level 50

Comment: no i got daedric arrows as a drop at lvl 25. thats how i knew they had them.

Comment: @doger Ok cool, didn'T get any yet, maybe has something to do with archery level too, never know...

Comment: my archery is 41 right know

Answer (score 9):

You can craft arrows and bolts at a forge (Fort Dawnguard forge in the case of bolts) if you have the Dawnguard DLC. 1 firewood and 1 metal ingot (substite metal with dragon bone in the case of Dragonbone arrows) make 24 arrows or 10 bolts. It is impossible to craft arrows in Skyrim sans Dawnguard/mods.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fletching skill in Skyrim; only a skill to recover more arrows, Hunter's Discipline which Recover twice as many arrows from dead bodies.

[Archery Skills](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery)

Edit: however, it seems to be added to the DawnGuard expansion

"If the Dawnguard plug-in has been installed, 1 Firewood can also be combined with a metal ingot to create 24 arrows or 10 bolts, of any craftable variety."

[Firewood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Firewood#Firewood)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, would you like to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

I took one of my housecarls, gave her one deadric arrow and took her other ones as well as her sword so she had to shoot with a bow. We went to the snow areas and hunted for anything to kill, the arrows are easier to spot in the snow. Just walking around and fast traveling to other snow areas I got 174 arrows in less that 15 minutes. When you are done give her back her fighting things and take yours

Answer (score 0):

From what everyone has stated, the dawngaurd expansion gives you that ability.  However, with everyone's statement about deadric arrows being shot from guards in cities or your housecarl are actually true.  I have a bountiful supply of ebony arrows at only level 12, and an extensive supply of dwarf, orc, and glass.  Elven arrows are a waste of time to "dupe" as they're near impossible to find on the ground.

I would suggest trying the guards method, and even go as far as "taking an arrow to the knee" in the wilds.  If you haven't noticed, you occasionally find arrows in your inventory if you get shot through with some.  Give a bandit that has arrows one of any arrow you want a heavy supply of, and then set him off.  Best to use LIGHT armor enchanted with reduction of restoration spells and spam the living daylights out of your best healing spell, and try to stand in a corner while you take a beating...and work up that light armor skill + restoration skill in the process...hey, you could even go as far as your block skill if your feeling "adventurous".

Good luck :D

Answer (score -2):

I read somewhere if you have a high enough pickpocket skill you can put a deadric arrow in Cynric Endell inventory and take all of his arrows - this will cause him to start practicing with the deadric and you can then farm them.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! You are answering a two-year old question which already has an accepted answer. This question probably doesn't need another answer. Try clicking the Unanswered tab at the top of the page to find questions which do not yet have accepted answers.

Comment: On that note, "I read somewhere" is not a good source. Please find either an actual source or confirm it yourself. :)