# Is there a way to craft arrows in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you make arrows?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/46885/how-do-you-make-arrows)

I'd like to craft arrows in Skyrim, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: there are mods that allow you to do so, however

Comment: Hi Sashley, welcome to Arqade! I'm glad you like the site, but we try to keep question bodies clear of anything other than the specific question.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 4):

There is no fletching skill in Skyrim; only a skill to recover more arrows, Hunter's Discipline which Recover twice as many arrows from dead bodies.

[Archery Skills](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Archery)

Edit: however, it seems to be added to the DawnGuard expansion

"If the Dawnguard plug-in has been installed, 1 Firewood can also be combined with a metal ingot to create 24 arrows or 10 bolts, of any craftable variety."

[Firewood](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Firewood#Firewood)

Comment: What does hunters disipline do?

Comment: Lets you reteive more than 1 arrow you shot to your enemie when you killed him.